# How to make a button run php code with ajax, without refreshing the page Shopping cart

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I got 3 buttons in my page cart.php
In cart.php i have all  the functions working.
When i'm in the checkout page and i want to add or remove an item from the cart my page refreshes.
Because my buttons functions is in the cart.php.
I call my cart function in my checkout.php

I dont know how to use ajax but i think ajax will help me on this...
How can i run this code without going to cart and sending to location:checkout..?

this is my buttons on cart.php.

```
 if(isset($_GET['plus'])){
   $_SESSION['product_'.$_GET['plus']]+=1;
   if($_SESSION['product_'.$_GET['plus']] < 1){
   header('Location: checkout.php');
   }else{
   header('Location: checkout.php');
    }
}


 if(isset($_GET['remove'])){
   $_SESSION['product_'.$_GET['remove']]--;
   if($_SESSION['product_'.$_GET['remove']] < 1){
   header('Location: checkout.php');
   }else{
   header('Location: checkout.php');
    }

}

 if(isset($_GET['delete'])){
    $_SESSION['product_'.$_GET['delete']] = '0';
    header('Location: checkout.php');
}

$btn_add='<a class="btn btn-success" href="cart.php?plus='.$id.'"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" add_btn></i></a>';

$btn_remove = '<a class="btn btn-warning" href="cart.php?remove='.$id.'"><i class="fa fa-minus fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" remove_btn></i></a>';

$btn_delete='<a class="btn btn-default delete_btn" href="cart.php?delete='.$id.'"><i class="fa fa-times fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <script>
    function doChanges(job,div,id) {

            try { req = window.XMLHttpRequest?new XMLHttpRequest(): 
                  new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
                 } catch (e) {  /* No AJAX Support */ }

            req.open('get','yourphp.php?job='+job+'&id='+id);

            // let the php echo the resultvalue

            req.onreadystatechange = function() {
             handleResponse(div);
            };
            req.send(null);
    }

    function handleResponse(div) {


           if ((req.readyState == 4) && (req.status == 200)) {
               val=req.responseText;
               document.getElementById(div).value=val;
           }
    }
    </script>

<div id="result"></div>

<a href="javascript:doChanges('inc','result','optionalcartitemid'> increase</a>
<a href="javascript:doChanges('dec','result','optionalcartitemid'> decrease</a>
```

Your php then needs to do the case work for inc/dec

if ($_GET[job]=='inc') then increase

if ($_GET[job]=='dec') then decrease

(or delete, whatever you want to happen)
any output will end up in responseText

Comment: but i want to increase and decrease my `$value` in my loop. And this code will display as text. Can i increase and decrease my `$value` in my loop with ajax?

Comment: Yes of course you can, you just fill in the result in your value. Update the value in your php and update the input field with js using the return. With your PHP: if ($_GET[job]=='inc') {$_SESSION['product_'.$_GET['plus']]+=1 } echo $_SESSION['product_'.$_GET['plus']]; - this is what you get in return for the js then